# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, cors, cloudflare

I am using a third party https api and getting this error

`has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I am using firebase hosting on spark plan with **Cloudflare**.

and the api is called from a subdomain like xyz.domain.com

Comment: have you tried adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to your header when calling the url?.

Comment: Yes I've tried it, no change. Any other solution?

Comment: Is API our own implementation?

Comment: No it's a paid service from thrid party

Comment: If you use Cloudflare API Gateway then you can allow cross origin access there: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/policies/access/cors/.

Comment: I don't have any control over api, and I'm only using cloudflare for ssl certificate

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer.

Looks like it's something on the server side that need to be set. You can either disable CORS on your browser (which is sub-optimal as other users may face the same problem) or do the setting on the server side. I don't know Cloudflare, but I guess (?) there is some way that you can set `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to `'*'`, which would then fix it.

Comment: You mean it has something to with cloudflare and not the third party api's server?

Comment: Or the third party. Something on the server/distributor side, which unfortunately I'm not familiar with at all.